# Green and Black screen on camera opeining using scandit barcode scanning sdk

Tags: android, uiview, camera

I sometimes get a green and black screen when I use the camera of my phone to scan a qrcode using the scandit sdk. I is not usual and comes very rarely but still is occurs twice a week.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interest in Scandit products and my apologies for the issue you are having.

Please contact us at the following link so we can provide you with the best support 
https://www.scandit.com/contact-us/

In order to help you, we would need to clarify the following questions:

- What is the device/OS, SDK version and platform in use?
- Could you please provide us with your minimal project sample?
- Could please describe all the steps to reproduce the issue and what you do to recover from the issue (i.e., restarting the Picker, the app or the whole phone)?
- Is the regular camera app working fine after the green/black screen issue?

Pedro
Scandit support

Comment: Any solution for this ? i am getting same issue in iOS . Not frequently but sometimes. @Pedro Penedo